# Select from 2 tables in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have 2 tables in my database, `tell` and `phone`:

Table `tell`:

- id int
- name varchar

Table `phone`:

- number int
- name nvarchar

I wanted to select id and name and number

Please help me.

Comment: As Andrew suggested, inner join would do the trick for you..
Read below link. this site is the good place to learn SQL..Happy learning!
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: Always, **always** use IDs in your tables.  **Always**.  If the name used in the "name" field is spelled differently in both tables (i.e. John Doe and John Dough) you're not going to get a match.  And that happens a **lot** in the "real world".

Answer (score 3):

You'll just need to join the two tables together on the name column:

```
   select
    t.id,
    t1.name,
    p.number
    from
    tell t
    inner join
    phone p
    on t.name = p.name
```

Comment: Technically, correct.  **Horrible** advice.  Never, **ever** join on a column that can contain misspellings.

Comment: Very very good point.  Just going on the design the OP gave us, didn't show any keys.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, p.number
  FROM tell t 
  JOIN phone p
    ON t.name = p.name
```